# ExtJS extend grid RowEditor plugin (to edit array)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've been using the [ExtJS grid row editing plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/extjs/examples/grid/row-editing.html) pretty liberally for CRUD operations in web applications. Now, I have a requirement to allow a database record to be edited along with a related collection/array (from another datastore) using this row editing plugin.

To do this I want to insert drag-n-drop grids inside of a row that has been selected for editing, one grid showing the available (unused) collection items on the left and another grid to hold the defined collection items on the right.

To illustrate what I am trying to do, here is the normal row editing plugin with a row selected for editing:

[image: grid with row editing]

I am trying to do this (drag-n-drop grids inside of row editor div):

[image: grid with row editing plus another grid inside]

To do this I have been trying to simply run something like `Ext.getCmp(???).add(myDnDGridPanel);` but I haven't found the right thing to attach this to (what to put in the question marks).

It seems reasonable enough to use this plugin to edit the related collection/array along with the database record. Does anyone know a simple way to add items to this row editor div?

Or... will I have to hack/extend the plugin to accomplish this?

Comment: Collection.. Hmm what I can think of is to extend the RowEditing and add the grids into it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is example `RowEditing` plugin modification which allows to add additional components. In this demo this is only a button, but it should be easy to customize.

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var body = this.editor.body;
            var container = body.down('.container-for-extra-content');
            if (!container) {
                container = Ext.core.DomHelper.insertAfter(body.last(), '<div class="container-for-extra-content"></div>', true);
                container.setWidth(this.editor.body.getWidth(true));
                container.setHeight(this.extraHeight);

                this.editor.getEl().setHeight(this.editor.getEl().getHeight() + this.extraHeight);
                this.editor.body.setHeight(this.editor.body.getHeight() + this.extraHeight);

                var panelConfig = {
                    renderTo: container,
                    items: [this.extraComponent]
                };
                Ext.create('Ext.Panel', panelConfig);
            }
        },
        delay: 1
    },
    extraHeight: 100,
    extraComponent: {
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'button', text: 'Aloha!' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/e2DzY/1/